# Meteor iron-router set route for overlay

Tags: javascript, css, meteor, overlay, iron-router

I wanted to implement the overlay effect like Atmospherejs.com by iron-router when overlay has the specific route (https://atmospherejs.com/?q=). Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you figured out this yet? I'm, trying to do the same hting

Comment: Hey Kim, check out the bellow answer of ajduke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't have route, by the way. As you can see nothing between domain name and query parameter.
and It just triggering of UI element on some click.

Something like following from CodeDrops might help for your usecase  -

Demo here: 
http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/index5.html

Code for same and article here:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/02/06/fullscreen-overlay-effects/

Comment: This actually isn't true. If you browse to `https://atmospherejs.com/?q=` the search menu is open, so it's not on a click.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a long time on how to accomplish this, but what I ended up doing was defining an empty action on the route.

```
Router.route('/login', {
    action: function () {

    },
    onAfterAction: function () {
        Session.set('loginOpen', true);
    }
});
```

This caused the route to be triggered, but didn't change the current template. I then set a session variable to open up the modal. This has been working great for me so far.

Comment: Yes, I think it can solve the problem too. What I did is I use the same route for both requests. Then have a hook in onAfterAction which check if there is a query "?q=". Open overlay if it does have.