# Can Meteor route changes without refresh/remove the previous page for overlay a page on the previous page?

Tags: meteor, routes, iron-router

Is there any method to keep previous page in the background, render the new page as an overlay with routing changed. I want to make post view pages overlay on a post list page. When the overlay page appears, the route url should change to the post page url and the post list should be visible on the background. By click back to the post list page, I can see the post list without rendering again. How to set my router for this?

Comment: possible duplicate- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934720/meteor-iron-router-set-route-for-overlay/27935841

Comment: @ajduke the question you mention is about "?q=", my question is about real route changes. Not "?q=" query changes.

Comment: http://www.producthunt.com/posts/stockroom is a good example of the result I want in Meteor.

Comment: can you look at answer and links in it - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27935841/755533

Comment: I did even before I post this question. And I know how to make the overlay. I'm just exploring if it's possible for my overlay to be responsive to Meteor route.

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? I'm trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @SangYooKim Not yet. Do you have any update? Please upvote this question BTW.